# Removing orphan vmware images

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I am trying to remove some VMWare images that were created by a machine that is no longer available.  We do not plan to use VMWare and would like to clear up the space.

I get a message Cannot delete [filename]... for all of the files in these directories.

Can anyone tell me how to delete them (short of reformatting)?

Thanks

-- edit --
The OS is Windows and the only machine that used the images isn't on the network any more.  Process Explorer is showing no processes accessing the files.

-- edit --
From the command prompt removed the system attribute and was able to delete the drive files, but still cannot remove the configuration files. WTF?  Anyway, I got most of the space back.

Comment: Host operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that both the files and the directories are not read only. Don't rely on the Windows Explorer properties page for that, as it has a bug that has existed since Windows 95. Turn on the attributes column instead.

If you're sure VMware isn't running and the files are not read only install [unlocker](http://ccollomb.free.fr/unlocker/) and use that to delete them.

Comment: During the weekend's maintenance window we isolated the servers from the rest of the network and were able to delete the files.  

Points for pointing out unlocker.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the files are in use. Is VMWare still running them?

Comment: Shut down the VMWare service and try again.

Answer (score 1):

On linux run lsof to see what process is access.
Linux does not actually delete a file until all processes that are accessing it are no longer running.

On windows use process explorer (sysinternals.microsoft.com) to see what process is accessing those files.